# Which is correct: "web host" or "web hoster"?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, internet

Which is the best way to refer to a **company that hosts your website**:

> My **web host** supports Ruby.

or

> My **web hoster** supports Ruby.

or

> My **web hosting service** supports Ruby.

Comment: What about **web server**?

Comment: Web server seems to me more commonly to refer to the actual machine serving the web pages, as opposed to the service supplying the hosting. That may be related to my background in IT, however.

Comment: @Edward can you be more specific about what these three terms are supposed to refer to?  Do you mean the machine running the software, the business that provides you the machine, or something else?

Comment: I don’t see how “web hoster” would ever be an expected form. One that *hosts* is a *host* not a *hoster*.

Comment: @nohat even Wired.com uses "web hoster": http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2007/10/controversial-r/

Comment: "hoster" is a commonly used term.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In casual speech and conversations on the internet, the usual terminology is "web host". If you need a more formal description then you might want to go with "web hosting service". "My web hoster supports Ruby" sounds distinctly odd to me. It might occur in a sentence like

> "Well-known web hoster doteasy today announced record profits".

Incidentally one way to compare terms like this is to count the number of Google hits you get with the words in quotes. I get

```
Web host              2,800,000 hits
Web hosting service   1,000,000 hits
Web hoster               30,000 hits
```

Comment: And "web server" has about 17,800,000 hits, making it a hands down winner over "web host".

Comment: @Chris: "web server" means something different to me.  A "server" is a computer that "serves" clients.  A "Web Server" is a computer that gives web pages to people who connect with a web browser.  Your Web Host operates your web server for you.

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard "web hoster" and "web hosting service" seems verbose to me. "Web host" is the generally accepted term, as far as I know.

Comment: This is one of those terms that is still being played out, e.g. even Reuters uses "web hoster": http://www.reuters.com/article/idUSL1562821520071016

Comment: That is interesting, and the first time I have ever seen that usage.

Comment: For me, that's just a sign of a not-so-tech-savvy editor. I remember reading about a woman who started a "Web-based Internet blog" in a major newspaper only a few months ago. Alas, being major doesn't imply being literate.

Answer (score 1):

I normally say *Ruby is included in the (web) hosting service for my website*; actually, I would say *Ruby on Rails is included in the (web) hosting service for my website*.

The difference for me is that saying *the web server includes Ruby* seems to mean it will never be removed; saying *the hosting service includes Ruby* means that it will be included until they don't change the service.

Answer (score 0):

Of the choices provided, the best way to refer to **a company that hosts your website** is your third option **web hosting service**.

Based on a COCA[1] query **web hosting** 6 times more common that **web host**, and **web hoster** yields no hits.  BTW, **web server** is 11 times more common that **web host**.  Personally, I find your third option the best: *My web hosting service supports Ruby.*  I could just as well go with: *My web server supports Ruby.*

[1] Google is generally accepted to be worthless as a corpus search tool.  This is why it is better to use a real corpus.  COCA is good for american english and BNC is good for british english.

Comment: But of what relevance is "web hosting", which will almost always refer to web hosting in general, and not be interchangeable with "web host/er"?
And why do you assert that "web host" is incorrect?

Comment: Chris, I'm sure that the term "web host" is in use. I don't accept that Google results are worthless.

Comment: @Colin The relevance of "web hosting" is that it is part of "web hosting service".

Comment: I already commented on this in reply to one of your comments, but for the benefit of this answer: a web server is not the same thing as a web host(ing service).

Comment: Incidentally, in the IT industry, we talk about web hosts all the time.  I'd say it's definitely correct.  I've never heard anyone say "web hoster".  In fact I don't recall every seeing the word hoster in any circumstances ever.

Answer (score 0):

- "Web host" - The physical computer
  hardware your web content is hosted on.
- "Web hosting service" - The
  product offered to a customer by a
  company.
- "Web hosting service provider" - The actual company. Shorter versions possible like "Web Hosting Provider" etc.

I don't agree that you could call the company the "Web host" and just randomly looking at some company web pages, none of them call themselves a "Web host" but a "XYZ Provider".

Just looking the google stats doesn't seem to be a good idea to me because...well, we would expect to find more references to the thing being provided than the providing company itself (you will find "car" more often than "car manufacturer").

"hosting provider" 2,030,000 results

Answer (score 0):

It is Web Host. "Web Hoster" is some kind of a slang, as there is no such word as "hoster".

Comment: You should provide citations for definitions and be careful about claiming the nonexistence of words. Apparently [hoster](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoster) is indeed a word, meaning exactly what it appears to mean.